# How to setup a secure connection on remote docker on remote server with pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, pycharm

## Pycharm

### SSH->Remote docker

We are using a remote interpreter for python on `Pycharm` which works great on an `SSH connection`. We are in a phase to convert our main work on `docker container`. It is important for us to keep to the development process on the `remote servers` and **not** on the `local computer`. But it is also important to be able to do it over `docker container`, and not just `ssh` as this saves a lot of time and effort when starting a `new development server`.

### Remote docker -> Securely remote docker

What we are seeking is a way to be able to make a `remote docker connection` within `Pycharm` securely.  It seems that when generating the `Tls` certificate, we need to bind it to the `host IP's`. This `IP/host bounding` prevents us to quickly start `new servers` for development as this force to generate a `certificate per IP`.

My question, is it possible to make a `secure connection` for `docker engine` from `Pycharm` without bound the `remote docker` to its `host IP`?

## Edit:

### Possible option so far

#### Wild card certificate:

As `Jan Garaj` suggestions, use a `wild card` certificate. Then connect each `new server` to a `new subdomain`. The wild card will be the same for each of them.

Pros: This suppose to do the trick
Cons: It requires to set up a new subdomain for each server

#### SSH tunnle

Set the `docker socket` to allow connection from `localhost`. Then each `developer` can set up an ssh tunnel from `his computer` to the `remote machine`. In `Pycharm` setup `python interpeter`  to  `docker socket` via `localhost` with the same `port` as the `tunnel`.

Answer (score 1):

Use (= buy or create/install/use own CA + generate) wildchar TLS certificate, which will cover all current servers and also any new servers.

Comment: is this the only option? to connect each dev server to a subdomain?

Comment: That is only option for secure TLS connection. Of course, you can be insecure and you can disable TLS cert verification and then you can use any TLS certs.